# Can't change data value when I upload html file into PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an html file uploaded into php and I try to change data between span (id= UserName) so I added javascript code into my html

```
$('.tdC').on('click',function(){
    $('#UserName').html("myName");
}
```

When I try to click on my `.tdC` element, the name of user changes for few seconds and then it turns back to the old value.

Any idea how to preserve the new value ?

Regards.

Comment: Are you causing the page to be redirected when you click the `.tdC` element? It sounds like the DOM is amended and then reloaded.

Comment: $('#UserName').text("myName");

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no it just changes the value, I don't have redirection when I click on .tdC

Comment: @DilipBelgumpi I still have the same thing even when I use text() instead html()